# adding and delete script doesn't work with removeChild()

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble with my code. the only thing i have to make is an add and delete button. The adding part is already done, but the delete part not. it keeps saying:

uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Code:

```
<input type="text" id="txtelement">
<button id="add">result</button>
<button id="delete">Delete latest</button>

<p id="divResult"></p>

<script>
//decline variable
var index = 1;

//adding option
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function(){
var newElement = document.createElement('div');
varElementid = 'div' + index++;

var node = document.getElementById('txtelement').value;
var newNode = document.createTextNode(node);

newElement.appendChild(newNode);

console.log(newElement);
document.getElementById('divResult').appendChild(newElement);
}

//delete option
document.getElementById('delete').onclick = function(){
var divResult = document.getElementById('divResult');
var alinea = divResult.querySelectorAll('p:last-child')[0];
console.log(alinea + ' word verwijderd...');

divResult.removeChild(alinea);
console.log('verwijderd!');

}
}
```

Comment: `alinea` isn't a child node of `divResult` - in fact, alinea would be an empty result I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:last-child` works slightly different than you think it does. `p:last-child` selects the last child of type *p(aragraph)* of [whatever parent node you called the method on]'. You don't want to select the `p`, you want to select the `div` you just inserted.

```
var alinea = divResult.querySelectorAll('div:last-child')[0]
```

Do note that your code doesn't handle the case yet where you delete more elements than you added.

Running code snippet:

```js
//decline variable
var index = 1;

//adding option
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    varElementid = 'div' + index++;

    var node = document.getElementById('txtelement').value;
    var newNode = document.createTextNode(node);

    newElement.appendChild(newNode);

    console.log(newElement);
    document.getElementById('divResult').appendChild(newElement);
  }

  //delete option
  document.getElementById('delete').onclick = function() {
    var divResult = document.getElementById('divResult');
    var alinea = divResult.querySelectorAll('div:last-child')[0];
    console.log(alinea + ' word verwijderd...');

    divResult.removeChild(alinea);
    console.log('verwijderd!');

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtelement">
<button id="add">result</button>
<button id="delete">Delete latest</button>

<p id="divResult"></p>
```

Comment: As a sidenote, I'm pretty sure your first comment is supposed to say "declare", not "decline" :-)